# Jquery form Ajax Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to submit a form using ajax in the background. I tried:

```
<div class="form-horizontal" id="form">
    <label for="name" class="control-label">Username</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <span id="name_input"><input type="text" name="name" id="medium" class='input-medium input-square'></span>
        <span class="help-inline" id = "ajax_load"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
        <button class="btn btn-red5" onclick="resolve()">Login</button>
        <input type="reset" class='btn btn-danger' value="Reset">
    </div>                                                  
</div>
```

And the Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var resolve = function () {
            jAlert('test', 'test');
                $('#ajax_load').html('<a href="#" class="btn btn-mini btn-square tip" title="Reloading"><img src="templates/img/ajax-loader.gif" alt=""></a>');
                $.ajax( {
                    url : 'plugin.php?plugin=test',
                    type : 'post',          
                    data: $("#form").serialize(),
                    success : function( resp ) {
                        if(resp.ajax_success == false) {

                        } else {
                            jAlert('test', 'test');
                        }
                    }
                });     
    };
</script>
```

I get an alert, but there is no form submit. I checked that with Live http headers.

Why does it not submit the form?

Comment: Thats the problem. If i change it to form it submit it directly in the browser. I dont know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### If it doesn't submit the form, because, the `#form` is not a form.

Change:

```
<div class="form-horizontal" id="form">
```

To:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="form">
```

You need to replace the `resp.ajax_success` with `resp`. Let us also know the response of the `plugin.php?plugin=test` URL.

---

If you don't want the `<form>` to get submitted on clicking on the Submit button, add a `return false;` at the end of the `resolve` function this way:

```
var resolve = function () {
    jAlert('test', 'test');
    $('#ajax_load').html('<a href="#" class="btn btn-mini btn-square tip" title="Reloading"><img src="templates/img/ajax-loader.gif" alt=""></a>');
    $.ajax( {
        url: 'plugin.php?plugin=test',
        type: 'post',          
        data: $("#form").serialize(),
        success: function( resp ) {
            if(resp.ajax_success == false) {

            } else {
                jAlert('test', 'test');
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
};
```

Comment: Thats the problem. If i change it to form it submit it directly in the browser. I dont know why..

Comment: @user1766080 In the end of the `resolve` function, please add `return false;`, so that the form doesn't get submitted.

Answer (score 1):

its because **you haven't used the form** you are serializing the data from div

```
<div class="form-horizontal" id="form">
```

not form the form

should be

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="form">
```

Comment: Thats the problem. If i change it to form it submit it directly in the browser. I dont know why..

Comment: @user1766080 yo not subnmit directly use either `return false;` or `preventdefault()`